# Ef core generated two cols with foreign keys with the same names

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After creating migrations I have two the same foreign keys.

Brand.cs:

```
public sealed class Brand : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> ProductItems { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Category.cs:

```
public sealed class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent API bounding:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Brands)
                .WithOne(c => c.Category)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
                .HasOne(b => b.Category)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

When I run a command 'dotnet ef migrations add' in the table Brands I have cols CategoryId and CategoryId1.
Why? Help, please.

Comment: Yes, work!
Mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two redundant mapping statements, but slightly different. If the second statment would look like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>()
    .HasOne(b => b.Category)
    .WithMany(c => c.Brands)
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.CategoryId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

...it would be completely redundant, and EF would ignore it.

In your case, because of the differences, EF considers this a second mapping between both entities and creates a second FK.